# Rxjava - only call network if not already in progress

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using retrofit and rxjava to create a repository that will call the network if no data has previously been retrieved and return the cache from memory if it is there.

However, where it fails is if you call the repository simultaneously it will call the network multiple times.  This is the current solution I have, with the repository being a singleton and storing whether a network call is already in progress and just returning the memory observable if so.

```
IDatabaseInteractor databaseInteractor;
INetworkInteractor networkInteractor;
Data data;

boolean networkCallInProgress = false;

@Override
public Observable<Data> getData() {
    Observable<Data> memoryObservable = data.getObservable();
    Observable<Data> networkObservable;

    //Sure this could be done in a better way...
    if (!networkCallInProgress) {
        getBoostersInPnetworkCallInProgressrogress = true;
        networkObservable = networkInteractor.getBoosters().toObservable()
                .doFinally(() -> networkCallInProgress = false);
    } else {
        networkObservable = Observable.empty();
    }

    return Observable.merge(memoryObservable, networkObservable)
            .firstElement()
            .toObservable()
            .onErrorResumeNext((throwable) -> memoryObservable)
            .flatMap(boosterData -> memoryObservable);
}
```

This works, but is there a more elegant solution using rxjava to know whether or not the network observable has already been called?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could use Singleton implementation via Dagger which really just keeps the link to the one time created object of you repository class.

According to multiple executions you could use one stream (e.g. rx subscription or even android's LiveData) to get data back from you repository (inside ViewModel for example) to your views and other to fetch your data.

1. When you create you repository you start to download with repeat
   rules to fetch data from server and fill the LiveData stream.
2. In
   your views you just listen to LiveData stream.

In this case you will call it only once without any checks and get your data from any view that should be attached to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do in the next way:

1.- The cloud and the disk data store should perform the same operations, then create a interface `DataStore`

```
interface DataStore {
  private void Observable<SOmeData> getTheData();
}
```

2.- Create your cache system.

3.- Create the `CloudDataStore` and a `DiskDataStore` and both must implement the `DataStore` interface. The `DiskDataStore` should contains the cache and also its wrapping its operations with the operations defined in the Cache

4.- Create a `DataStoreFactory`and inject both (the cloud and disk data stores). Here, you can create methods like:

```
private DataStore createDataStoreForUserListForExample(boolean force) {
    if (force) //you want a network call because maybe is a refresh from a pull to refresh
        return cloudDataStore
    else {
        if (cache.usersListIsCached()) return diskDataStore
        else return cloudDataStore
    }
}
```

5.- Now, create your repository and inject the `DataStoreFactory` inside. Here you should have a function like:

```
public void Observable<SomeData> getTheList(boolean force) {
  DataStore ds = factory.createDataStoreForUserListForExample(force);
  return ds.getTheData();
}
```